# visibility:visible em div javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho a seguinte div que esta oculta:

```
  <div class="card" id="cnpj_erro" style="visibility:hidden">
       <div class="body">
            <div class="header bg-red">
                <h2>
                    CNPJ inválido <small>Confira os números</small>
                </h2>
            </div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

E a função:

```
<script>
        function verificarValidacaoCNPJ() {
            debugger;
            var valCNPJ = !document.getElementById("txCNPJ_cad_emp") ? "" : document.getElementById("txCNPJ_cad_emp").value;
            if (!validarCNPJ(valCNPJ)) {
                document.getElementById('cnpj_erro').setAttribute('style', 'visibility:visible');
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('cnpj_erro').setAttribute('style', 'visibility:hidden');
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Ela está validando certo, sem problemas, porém não estou conseguindo trocar a atributo 'style', 'visibility' para que o mesmo seja exibido ou ocultado. 
Debungando quando ele entra na opção `document.getElementById('cnpj_erro').setAttribute('style', 'visibility:visible');`

retorna `Return value: undefined`

Comment: Já tentou utilizar `document.getElementById('cnpj_erro').style.visibility = "visible"`?

Comment: foi o primeiro que eu tentei, tambem tentei `document.getElementById('cnpj_erro').visibility = "visible"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como dito nos comentários, para você alterar uma propriedade do estilo de um elemento, basta fazer:

```
document.getElementById('cnpj_erro').style.visibility = "visible";
```

Veja o exemplo:

```js
var visible = false;

function toggle() {
  if (!visible) {
    document.getElementById('cnpj_erro').style.visibility = 'visible';
    visible = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('cnpj_erro').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    visible = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card" id="cnpj_erro" style="visibility:hidden">
  <div class="body">
    <div class="header bg-red">
      <h2>
        CNPJ inválido <small>Confira os números</small>
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="toggle()">Click</button>
```

Se você tentou fazer isso e não funcionou, você deve ter feito errado.

Comment: fiz exatamente da maneira que você colocou, copiei o seu código até, mas ainda não funciona, ele entra na função sem problema passa até pelo visible = true sem problemas, sei que devo estar fazendo algo errado, vou refazer tudo do inicio pra tentar ver o que é.

Comment: Então monte um [mcve] de como está fazendo e coloque-o na pergunta. Deveria funcionar, como demonstrado.

Comment: foi vacilo meu, tinha um text com o mesmo id mais acima, devo ter colocado quando estava fazendo algum teste. Funcionou blz, obrigado!